# why design is different with simulator and actual view

Tags: ios, xib

please refer the following picture 
[image]

I think the blank area should the same size with status bar. How do I adjust this view to remove the blank area?

---

**Edit**

the view I create with xib by default.

Comment: Are you using Auto-Layout?

Comment: yes, by default, it ticked, but I also tried untick it, still same.

Comment: Does it work while it is ticked?

Comment: no. I think it's not the auto layout problem.

Comment: Is the status bar hidden before the map view is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select your view controller (not the view) in storyboard.
- In Attribute Inspector you should see options for Top Bar, Bottom Bar
  etc. In one of them will be the option for Status bar.
- Select None for that option. You have disabled status bar for this scene.
- Now reposition and resize your view in question, ensure that it's height
  must be same as screen height (e.g. 480 for normal,960 for ratina and so on)

Note that there is also an additional option in your plist file named `"Status bar is initially Hidden."` Set this to `Yes`. And you should be done.

Comment: correct, it's the problem. just don't know why apple try to confuse us.